# Xcode 7 Autocompletion doesn't index newly imported class

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, appdelegate

I have imported my custom class file another class and when ever i tried to create object of that imported class the auto completion doesn't show that class in the suggestions. Auto completion shows all other thing perfectly like built in class, methods, objects but not showing the class name of imported class.
In my case i have imported `HomeViewController.h` file into `AppDelegate.m` file and when i type `HomeViewController` it doesn't show this class in the auto completion box.

[Here is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDKsw.png)

Comment: does it throw any error if you enter HomeViewController  ?

Comment: try to do clean and build or restart ur xcode. This should fix most of the issue.

Comment: Possibly your mac is out of power and needs to be charged to fully utilize the autocompletion. Jokes aside, a note regarding tags to your question: note that you should only include relevant tags, and only one tag from the same family of tags. In this case, I've removed `swift` tag (no Swift whatsoever in this question) and `xcode` tag (duplicate tags from same family: just choose one tag from same family: in this case I've left the `xcode7` tag).

Comment: i have restarted xcode many times and i don't know how to clean the build. Can you please quote a link of how to clean xcode build.

Comment: @dfri Thank you sir for correcting me. I am new to this website and doesn't know all the rules. I will be careful next time to not to do such sort of mistakes.

Comment: cmd + shft +K to clean and cmd+B to build

Comment: Thank you so very much sir. My Problem is solved.

Comment: @SyedeHussaini No worries, and happy to help; consider my comment as information and in no way scolding. Welcome to StackOverflow!